# When on New Caprica, can a crisis effect move a player from Detention to the Medical Center?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

When on New Caprica in the Pegasus expansion, can a crisis effect move a player from Detention to the Medical Center?  The Cylon players allowed it in the individual instance to try and keep the game running and fun, but we had some doubts about whether or not it is legal to be forced out of Detention simply by a crisis forcing the current player to move someone on New Caprica to the Medical Center.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'de say no.  Even thought the rules don't spell it out explicitly I think it's clear enough.

First, detention and the bring are treated to be the same thing, especially for player powers.

Second, according to the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Battlestar_Galactica/bsg_FAQ_1-1-1.pdf) (page 2, bottom of the first column) nothing can move a player out of the brig except a successful skill check for the brig location action.  So by extension this applies to the detention center.

Third, thematically it didn't happen (spoiler follows).

> When Tigh was in the detention center and Cavil ripped his eye out, he left him there.  Even when he kicked the snot out of him as well he left them there.  He totally should have gone to the medical tent but didn't.

Comment: Thank ya--the FAQ listed there had the full answer in it:  Q: Do forced-movement effects such as Louanne “Kat” 
Katraine’s “Stim Junkie” ability or the effects of crisis 
cards that force a player to move to Sickbay affect 
characters in the “Brig” or “Detention” locations? 
A: No.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing an FAQ somewhere that addressed this. No effect can move a player from detention/the brig short of a political card providing the means for it, or passing the skill check. That's it.